# query to find various combinations search and counts in single query oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi all i have come across a requirement to find out the counts for the columns (col1,col2,col3) across a specific schema (SCHEMA_A) ,but here is a catch i have to find out a combination of all the column in order to get the counts how many tables use VALID_FROM_DATE, VALID_FROM_DATE, TIMESTAMP ,below are more details

**Database - Oracle 11g**

**Table searching in - DBA_TAB_COLUMNS**

**col1 - VALID_FROM_DATE**

**col2 - VALID_TO_DATE**

**col3 - TIMESTAMP**

combination search along with counts across all the tables

```
combination 1 
VALID_FROM_DATE + VALID_TO_DATE + TIMESTAMP

combination 2
VALID_FROM_DATE + VALID_TO_DATE 

combination 3 
VALID_FROM_DATE + TIMESTAMP

combination 4 
VALID_TO_DATE + TIMESTAMP

combination 5 
VALID_FROM_DATE

combination 6 
VALID_TO_DATE

combination 7 
TIMESTAMP
```

**Query - I am trying**

```
select count(distinct table_name) from DBA_TAB_COLUMNS
where owner='SCHEMA_A'
and column_name in ('VALID_FROM_DATE','VALID_TO_DATE','TIMESTAMP')
order by table_name;
```

but how to achieve the above combinations (1-7) all in a single query to capture the counts also overall percentage ,is it possible to acheive in a simplest possible way one single query block

```
percentage - round(100*ratio_to_report(count(*)) over (), 2) percentage
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: Hi Rakesh, it is not completely clear to me what are you need to achieve. You say "identify columns" but in the query you are looking for a table name (delete the comma between distinct n table_name). Can you please provide us with test data and result you need to get

Comment: @ekochergin - updated the question now , i need to find out the counts how many tables user the above columns whether all the tables have combination 1 through 7 or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe full outer joins will work here.

The subqueries here are being used to find out tables having that columns and the results is then being joined to provide us with all possible combination.

On the last step the combinations are to be counted.

```
select case when vfd.table_name is not null then 'VALID_FROM_DATE' else null end VALID_FROM_DATE, 
       case when vtd.table_name is not null then 'VALID_TO_DATE' else null end VALID_TO_DATE, 
       case when ts.table_name  is not null then 'TIMESTAMP' else null end TIMESTAMP_col,
       count(1) tables_cnt
  from            (select table_name from dba_tab_cols where column_name = 'VALID_FROM_DATE') vfd -- tables with 'VALID_FROM'
  full outer join (select table_name from dba_tab_cols where column_name = 'VALID_TO_DATE') vtd   -- tables with 'VALID_TO'
    on vfd.table_name = vtd.table_name
  full outer join (select table_name from dba_tab_cols where column_name = 'TIMESTAMP') ts        -- tables with 'TIMESTAMP'
    on vfd.table_name = ts.table_name
 where vfd.table_name is not null 
    or vtd.table_name is not null
    or ts.table_name is not null
 group by case when vfd.table_name is not null then 'VALID_FROM_DATE' else null end, 
          case when vtd.table_name is not null then 'VALID_TO_DATE' else null end, 
          case when ts.table_name  is not null then 'TIMESTAMP' else null end
```

The subqueries I've used here to achieve better readability only. In case if someone yells at you that sub-queries are wrong here, you may use the following version

```
select case when vfd.table_name is not null then 'VALID_FROM_DATE' else null end VALID_FROM_DATE, 
       case when vtd.table_name is not null then 'VALID_TO_DATE' else null end VALID_TO_DATE, 
       case when ts.table_name  is not null then 'TIMESTAMP' else null end TIMESTAMP_col,
       count(1) tables_cnt
  from user_tab_cols vfd -- tables with 'VALID_FROM'
  full outer join user_tab_cols vtd   -- tables with 'VALID_TO'
    on vfd.table_name = vtd.table_name
    and vfd.column_name = 'VALID_FROM_DATE'
    and vtd.column_name = 'VALID_TO_DATE'
  full outer join user_tab_cols ts        -- tables with 'TIMESTAMP'
    on vfd.table_name = ts.table_name
    and vfd.column_name = 'VALID_FROM_DATE'
    and ts.column_name = 'TIMESTAMP'
 where vfd.column_name = 'VALID_FROM_DATE' 
    or vtd.column_name = 'VALID_TO_DATE' 
    or ts.column_name = 'TIMESTAMP'
 group by case when vfd.table_name is not null then 'VALID_FROM_DATE' else null end, 
          case when vtd.table_name is not null then 'VALID_TO_DATE' else null end, 
          case when ts.table_name  is not null then 'TIMESTAMP' else null end;
```

In case of performance issue, adding an index on column_name of dba_tab_cols will PROBABLY help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this. I'm using multiple CTE to split the logic up in steps

- x_dba_tab_columns cte is just test data to mimic dba_tab_columns
- all_tables cte is a distinct list of tables
- table_w_cols cte joins each table to x_dba_tab_columns filtered on column and returns 1 if the column exists and 0 if not

and the final select is just a case statement to calculate the combination.

```
with x_dba_tab_columns (table_name, column_name)
AS
(
  SELECT 'TABLE1','VALID_FROM_DATE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TABLE1','VALID_TO_DATE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TABLE1','TIMESTAMP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TABLE2','VALID_TO_DATE' FROM DUAL
  
), all_tables (table_name)
AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT table_name FROM x_dba_tab_columns
), table_w_cols (table_name, vfd, vtd, ts)
AS
(
SELECT 
  t.table_name, 
  NVL2(vfd.table_name,1,0) vfd,
  NVL2(vtd.table_name,1,0) vtd,
  NVL2(ts.table_name,1,0) ts
  FROM all_tables t 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN x_dba_tab_columns vfd ON vfd.table_name = t.table_name AND vfd.column_name = 'VALID_FROM_DATE'
       LEFT OUTER JOIN x_dba_tab_columns vtd ON vtd.table_name = t.table_name AND vtd.column_name = 'VALID_TO_DATE'  
       LEFT OUTER JOIN x_dba_tab_columns ts ON ts.table_name = t.table_name AND ts.column_name = 'TIMESTAMP'  
)
SELECT 
  table_name,
  CASE 
    WHEN (vfd = 1 AND vtd = 1 AND ts = 1) THEN 'combination 1'
    WHEN (vfd = 1 AND vtd = 1) THEN 'combination 2'
    WHEN (vfd = 1 AND ts = 1) THEN 'combination 3'
    WHEN (vtd = 1 AND ts = 1) THEN 'combination 4'
    WHEN (vfd = 1) THEN 'combination 5'
    WHEN (ts = 1) THEN 'combination 7'
    WHEN (vtd = 1) THEN 'combination 6'
  END as combination 
FROM table_w_cols;

TABLE1  combination 1
TABLE2  combination 6
```

Comment: Thanks fir the template , i want the counts 1 means and 0 means ?

Comment: as I stated, "table_w_cols cte joins each table to x_dba_tab_columns filtered on column and returns 1 if the column exists and 0 if not". So if column "vfd" = 1 then that table has a column VALID_FROM_DATE.

Comment: Can you mark question as answered please ?